# Consuming spring Rest api

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I want to create a restful webservice with spring mvc. I followed some tutorials and could
work out how to create a webservice with spring. But I am not understanding how to
make it work for my requirement. 
My requirement is a company xyz sends an xml file with its usage details to my company abc.
NOw my company has to consume that xml file with spring rest api and store the details in 
database.Any help is appreciated.
In spring webservices I have only seen examples like crud opeartion for employees,persons
but how to match it with my requirement.
Thanks in advance.
Here are sample example I looked into:

> "https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/wa-spring3webserv/"
>   "http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/"

suppose the following is the xml my rest api is consuming and I want to put those details in a database, how can I do it.

```
<Usage xmlns="http://www.abc.com/abc/It/schema"       
xmlns:id="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19770/-2/2009/schema.xsd">    
    <timestamp>2010-01-01T12:38:11.123Z</timestamp>    
   <proxy>        
  <address>host address</address>        
 <platforms>xyz</platform>    
 </proxy>    
  <as> <label>Label name</label><name>sdff</name>        
  <id><a_id>34D87XHF72122</a_id><line>sadf</line>                                            
   <title>adffdn<title>
  <version>3.1</version> <creator>abc Corp.</creator>
  <license>abcCorp. </license></id>
```

Comment: company xyz sends an xml file, can you show a sample xml.

Comment: create a REST method that accepts POST verb and application/xml content-type. Company XYZ will then send a POST request with the xml in the body, and your service will read from the body.

Answer (score 1):

If the company xyz is sending an XML file to your server, you would want to use a method similar to this to handle the request and not return any content back:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/xyz", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"text/xml"})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void processXML(@RequestBody Object someObject) {

}
```

EDIT: See the Spring docs on @RequestBody: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody

Comment: :Thanks for the response. Could you also please give any suggestion on how to store it in the database.

Comment: Normally you use JPA/Hibernate in your database (DAO) layer. You'd probably want to ask another question related to this or edit your existing question to be more specific.